# AWK output with IF condition

Tags: shell, awk

I intend to read a file, and whenever the `VALID1` or `VALID2` fields are different from zero they must be printed, together with the identifier field (`Store: xx | Workstation:yy` )
For example, below is an example of the contents of the file:

```
Store: 01 | Workstation:01
VALID1:3
VALID2:0
Store: 01 | Workstation:02
VALID1:0
VALID2:0
Store: 02 | Workstation:01
VALID1:3
VALID2:3
Store: 02 | Workstation:02
VALID1:0
VALID2:0
Store: 02 | Workstation:03
VALID1:5
VALID2:5
Store: 03 | Workstation:01
VALID1:0
VALID2:0
Store: 03 | Workstation:02
VALID1:0
VALID2:4
```

I want the following output:

```
Store: 01 | Workstation:01
VALID1:3
Store: 02 | Workstation:01
VALID1:3
VALID2:3
Store: 02 | Workstation:03
VALID1:5
VALID2:5
Store: 03 | Workstation:02
VALID2:4
```

Tried to do with awk but no success atm (`$BODYTEXT` is the input file)

```
awk 'BEGIN 
    $1 ~ /Store/ {a = $1}
    $1 ~ /VALID1/ {b = $1}
    $1 ~ /VALID2/ {c = $3}
        if (b <>0 || c<>0){
            if (b=0)
                {print a,c}
            else if (c=0)
                    {print a,b}         
                else 
                    {print a,b,c}
            }
     '$BODYTEXT
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F: '/^Store/{store=$0; pstore=0} /^VALID/ && $2{if(!pstore){print store; pstore=1}; print}' <file>
```

Output :

```
Store: 01 | Workstation:01
VALID1:3
Store: 02 | Workstation:01
VALID1:3
VALID2:3
Store: 02 | Workstation:03
VALID1:5
VALID2:5
Store: 03 | Workstation:02
VALID2:4
```